# Eclipse Export Signed Package adds the drawables directory twice, doubling apk size!

Tags: android, eclipse, export, drawable, filesize

I have noticed this since about 2.1.  I believe the problem is in the Eclipse Export to APK plugin or else somewhere in my setup (though I have no idea where it could be).

Basically, all of a sudden my APK sizes doubled! Some investigating revealed that Eclipse was now including the drawable directory (and the raw, layout, and xml directories) twice.  It includes it once under the res subdirectory and once under the root directory of the application.

So, instead of having a directory structure like:

```
- com
- META-INF
- res
  - drawable
  - layout
  - raw
  - xml
...
```

I have:

```
- com
- drawable
- layout
- META-INF
- raw
- res
  - drawable
  - layout
  - raw
  - xml
- values
- values-fr
- xml
```

Has anyone else experienced this?  Does anyone know why this might be?  It increased my app size from 3mb to over 6mb, which is a big deal.

My current workaround is to export an unsigned package with eclipse, remove the drawable, layout, raw, and xml files from the root directory, then manually sign it and zipalign it.

If you want to look at the apk, check out [this apk (with the problem)](http://emweather.googlecode.com/files/EmWeather-0.9.5.6.3.apk) and [this apk (that I have fixed manually)](http://emweather.googlecode.com/files/EmWeather-0.9.5.6.4.apk).  Both work, one is just twice as big.

I am using Eclipse SDK, Version: 3.5.2, Build id: M20100211-1343, Android Development Toolkit Version: 10.0.1.v201103111512-110841, Though I have had the problem for the last couple of ADTs, since 2.1 came out.  It doesn't seem to matter what APK level I compile for.

Thanks for any help, insight!

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this finally!

For some reason, there was an error in my .classpath file, I have never edited this file myself but in all the migrations between machines, versions of eclipse, and versions of the SDK, it must have slipped it.

It read:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="res"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Changing it to:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Fixed the problem.  Yippee!